# SQL date as bigint

Tags: sql

I have a DB with date looks like BIGINT "15321600".
It's represent 17/2/2017

How can I convert it?

edit:
I understood that the number represent the minute passed from 1/1/1988...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I see you have made an edit since the last comment was posted but still haven't stated which Database product you are using. Is this mysql, postgres, sql server, oracle, teradata, db2, sqlite, access, mariadb, vertica, hana, redshift, azure, etc? The syntax would be different for nearly every one of these.

Answer (score 0):

You really need logic to specify what the conversion is.  My trial-and-error, it looks like minutes since 1988-01-01 produces your value.

That means that you can use logic like this

```
select date '1988-01-01' + col * interval '1' minute
```

Of course, date/time functions vary by database, so the exact syntax might be different in your database.